# Swift, iOS15, UIKit, CollectionView header issue

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc

I am testing **iOS15** and some new functionalities of **UIKit**. I've encountered some issues, not sure how to solve them. ***I did not change that code**. This is just a piece of code that worked perfectly with the iOS 14, now after updating my target, it throws an error.*

Xcode crashes the moment when my **custom header** for the **UICollectionView** of type **UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader** is being returned for the **dataSource**. Here is my code:

```
private func configureDataSource() {
      dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Follower>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: { (collectionView, indexPath, followers) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FollowerCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! FollowerCell
         cell.set(on: followers)
         return cell
      })
      
      dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { (collectionView, kind, indexPath) in
         let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                                                      withReuseIdentifier: FollowersCollectionHeaderView.reuseId,
                                                                      for: indexPath) as! FollowersCollectionHeaderView
         
         header.set(with: self.user)
         return header
      }
   }
```

The log says:

> the view returned from
> -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: does not match the element kind it is being used for. When asked for a view
> of element kind 'FollowersCollectionHeaderView' the data source
> dequeued a view registered for the element kind
> 'UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader'.

I did cast **UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader** to **FollowersCollectionHeaderView**, therefore I am not sure what is the issue here.

I've watched **WWDC21** **what's new in UIKit** but haven't seen any mentioning of any change for that particular code.

Any suggestions, what to fix in that code?

Comment: Most likely an iOS bug. I'm getting the same issue with code that worked fine on all previous OS versions.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hey, yes I did but since I updated my Xcode to Xcode13, I've encountered some other issues. Nevertheless, I will post the solution

Comment: I don't see where you call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618103-register in the above. You do call it in your answer code.

Comment: Hey Matt, I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the partial solution that I came up with. Apple recommends using object's ID as a reference for the collectionView cells.

```
enum Section { case main }


var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Follower.ID>!

// MARK: - Collection View configurations
    fileprivate lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: UIHelper.createCompositionalLayout())
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        collectionView.register(FollowersCollectionHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: FollowersCollectionHeaderView.reuseId)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    fileprivate lazy var snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Follower.ID> = {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Follower.ID>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        let itemIdentifiers = followers.map { $0.id }
        snapshot.appendItems(itemIdentifiers, toSection: .main)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
        return snapshot
    }()
    
    fileprivate func updateData(with followers: [Follower]) {
        snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Follower.ID>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        let itemIdentifiers = followers.map { $0.id }
        snapshot.appendItems(itemIdentifiers, toSection: .main)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<FollowerCell, Follower.ID> { [weak self]
            cell, indexPath, followerID in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            let followerArray = self.followers.filter { $0.id == followerID }
            
            if let follower = followerArray.first {
                cell.set(on: follower)
            }
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Follower.ID>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration,
                                                                for: indexPath,
                                                                item: itemIdentifier)
        }
        
        let headerRegistration = createSectionHeaderRegistration()
        dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { collectionView, elementKind, indexPath in
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableSupplementary(using: headerRegistration, for: indexPath)
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func createSectionHeaderRegistration() -> UICollectionView.SupplementaryRegistration<FollowersCollectionHeaderView> {
        return UICollectionView.SupplementaryRegistration<FollowersCollectionHeaderView>(
            elementKind: FollowersCollectionHeaderView.reuseId) { [weak self] supplementaryView, elementKind, indexPath in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            supplementaryView.set(with: self.user)
        }
    }
```